# Funny Django `NoReverseMatch error`

Tags: python, html, django

Everything was working until I decided to use django `extends` for some part of my template to make them reuseable and now I am getting
`NoReverseMatch error`.

**url.py**:

```
url(r'^school/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<name>[-\w]+)/$', views.school_profile, name='school'),
```

**views.py**:

```
def school_profile(request, id, name):
    #Some actions here...
```

**index.html**:

```
<p class='mini_links'><a href="{% url 'mysite:school' user.school.id user.school|slugify %}">{{user.school|title}} </a></p>
```

That is the html line that is generating the error and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

**NOTE:**

Formally the html link is just in `index.html` but I have now extracted *(extract.html)* away and it is now coming through:

**index.html**:

```
{% extends 'mysite/base.html' %}

{% block mainBody %} 
    {% include 'mysite/extract.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

I really can't figure out what I am not doing right.

**Error Stack:**
    NoReverseMatch at /mysite/

```
Reverse for 'school' with arguments '('', u'')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/
Django Version:     1.6
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'school_profile' with arguments '('', u'')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 429
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version:     2.7.9
Python Path:    

['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\HubEnv\\Scripts\\myApp',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Sun, 29 Mar 2015 21:50:52 +0100
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reverse a namespaced URL but you don't seem to have defined one. Just remove the `mysite:` namespace from your reverse:

```
{% url 'school' user.school.id user.school|slugify %}
```

**Update**: Your code and stack trace are not confirming each other. It looks like you did not paste the actual code you are running. So either change your reverse to `{% url 'mysite:school' %}` or your url name to `..., name='school_profile')`

Comment: I tried this but I got `url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'namespace'`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. You are not including another `urls.py`, so you cannot use `namespace` here. See my updated answer

Comment: I have also tried the edited answer and I still get `NoReverseMatch error`.

Comment: Is this your main `urls.py` or the one in your application directory? If so, please post the main one too.

Comment: It is the one in my app directory `(url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.urls', namespace='mysite')),)`.

Comment: I have updated the question with the stack trace? If I get you correctly?.

Comment: Your error message is about `school_profile` while your code does not show that. See my updated answer.

Comment: That is the error stack trace. I actually changed `school_profile` to `school` because the latter was cause the code to have horizontal scrollbar which makes reading codes on SO terrible.